# javascript cannot add element into dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashmap

I want to create a structure of dictionary `lineChartData{ datasets:[ {dataset },{dataset }...{ dataset} ] }` and in each dataset, {data:[1,2,3,...]}. But whenever I try to print console, I always get "[object object]", can anyone help me out please??

```
var lineChartData = {}; //declare an object
lineChartData.datasets = [];
for (line = 0; line < symptomSet.size; line++) {
    y = [];
    dataset = {};
    dataset.data = []; 
    for(i=0; i< Object.keys(dataMap).length ; i++) {
      if(dataMap[Object.keys(dataMap)[i]][symptoms[line]]==null) {
        dataset.data.push(0);
      } else {
        dataset.data.push(dataMap[Object.keys(dataMap)[i]][symptoms[line]]);
      }
    }
    console.log("dataset:"+dataset); //always print "[object object]"
    lineChartData[datasets].push(dataset);
}
```

Comment: Do `console.log("dataset:", dataset)` instead... Concatenating a string with an object will execute `dataset.toString` which returns `"[object object]"`.

Comment: Oh great it works!! I thought my mechanism is not working, but it's actually the displaying not working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turning [Derek 朕會功夫’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625208/javascript-cannot-add-element-into-dictionary#comment82208337_47625208) into an answer:

Do `console.log("dataset:", dataset)` instead. Concatenating a string with an object will execute `dataset.toString`, which returns `"[object object]"`.